# How to get only column name from relation

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

How to join column, that when i launch my function, he return me only columns name instead of `entity_columnName`.

I'm using TypeORM, and i try this;

```
const data = this.conn.getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder('user');
data.leftJoinAndSelect('user.orders', 'orders');
data.getRawMany();
```

but return me:

```
firstName: ...
lastName: ...
age: ...
order_name: ...
order_price: ...
```

instead of:

```
firstName: ...
lastName: ...
age: ...
name: ...
price: ...
```

can someone tell me how do this? thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

How are your User and Order entities defined?

If you define a relation (e.g. OneToMany) with the `eager: true` option, then TypeORM will automatically include the related entities when you query using the repository `*find` methods. It won't do this when you use the QueryBuilder, where you have to add them such as with `leftJoinAndSelect()` (as you have done).

An example from an Invoice entity that has OneToMany line items:

```
  @OneToMany(
    () => InvoiceLineItem,
    (item: InvoiceLineItem) => item.invoice,
    { eager: true }
  )
  items: InvoiceLineItem[]
```

Per the example, if I were then to `find()` or `findMany()` invoices, then the related objects, `items` will be included as well because `eager: true`.

This behaviour might translate well to your situation with users and orders.

Also be aware of the differences between `getMany()` and `getRawMany()` when using the query builder.

If you use `getMany()` then TypeORM will automagically give you entities back (e.g. you'd get an instance of `User` with property `orders` that is an array of `Order` instances). The property names will be correct.

Since you added the NestJS tag to your question, also understand serialization:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization

There is a built-in `ClassSerializerInterceptor` that comes with NestJS that you might find useful.

In your controller you can decorate the class or any of its methods e.g.

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```

This will transform the response to JSON, and will apply the rules specified with `class-transformer` decorators on the entity/DTO class.

If you were to use this interceptor, the response sent to the client will have your desired property names.

If you *really* want to modify the response that your client gets back, you can also look into writing your own Interceptor.